# File attached in a word document

Tags: ms-word

I am creating a Word document template, I would like users who use this form to also be able to manage an attached file. The template is written with Microsoft Word 2000. Is there a way to create a part of the template that can be used to manage such an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by dragging the file I wanted to attach directly into the Word document.